# What is sanity testing? And what is its advantage in mobile testing

Tags: testing

I don't know the benefit of sanity testing. Please feel free to comment. What is sanity testing?

Am I actually wasting time in doing this because after this I will do regression testing.

Comment: "The advantage of a sanity test, over performing a complete or rigorous test, is speed."

Answer (score 4):

**In mobile terms:**

In mobile applications there are following types of testing:

1) Sanity test

2) Feature test

3) Defect verification

4) Regression test

5) Hopper test

**Sanity test** - It is a rapid testing of features to check the basic features and stability. Testing basically boils down in finding **fall/not fall** and if there are no rough errors.

**Sanity check** is a very basic check to see if all software components compile with each other  without a problem.

It can be done by developers.

This is just to make sure that developers have not defined conflicting or multiple functions or global variable definitions. Sanity test is usually unscripted.

Sanity testing helps to identify the dependent missing objects.

Sanity test is used to determine a small section of the application is still working after a minor change.

Sanity testing can be narrow and deep. As a narrow regression test that focuses on one or a few areas of functionality.

More on [Sanity testing Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_testing).

Answer (score 1):

Sanity Testing is the subset of Regression Testing and it is performed when we do not have enough time for doing testing. Sanity testing is the surface level testing where QA engineer verifies that all the menus, functions, commands available in the product and project are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sanity test : It is a basic test to cover positive flows particular to the build delivered to QA/Testing.

For example: Create Update Delete Flows.
if Create build delivered to QA: Sanity Flows should contain Particular entity is created sucessfully or not. Then Sanity Test will get passed we can Start with Functional testing like

Differnt  kinds of input to create entity and check expected behaviour.